# Add record to dataframe based on boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which each record represents a user that visited a page.

```
userID   pageID
1          1
1          2
2          1
```

I would like to add to this dataframe with the oposite information (a user record that has not visited a page) and add a boolean to differentiate visits from no visit

```
userID   pageID   visit
1          1        1
1          2        1
2          1        1
2          2        0
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.assign(visit=1).set_index(['userID','pageID']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
   userID  pageID  visit
0       1       1      1
1       1       2      1
2       2       1      1
3       2       2      0
```

Comment: @psyvic - what is error?